# Instr returning unexpected match

Tags: excel, vba

I'm building a "Edit Product" userform, and I'm using instr to find the searched for product from its primary assigned code. Problem: it is returning wrong product from the search. Let's say I want the product with code "1", it gives me product with code "13" (which is the latest item in the test database with 13 items), I think it takes the first indexed answer from all the results with "1" on them, instead of a direct match. Maybe I should use a match instead of a instr, since it'll always be a integer value on the cell?

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Dim Abas As Worksheet
    Dim linha As Integer
    Dim xPesq As String
    Dim xCel As String
    Dim xPlan As String
    
    Sheets("Produtos").Select
    Planilha1.Activate
    xPlan = Planilha1.Name
    xPesq = Edi_Pro.TextBox1.Text
    linha = 3
    
    Set Abas = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(xPlan)
    With Abas
        
        While .Cells(linha, 2) <> Empty
            
            xCel = .Cells(linha, 2)
            If InStr(1, UCase(xCel), UCase(xPesq), 0) Then
                Edi_Pro.TextBox2.Value = .Cells(linha, 3)
                Edi_Pro.TextBox3.Value = .Cells(linha, 4)
                Edi_Pro.TextBox4.Value = .Cells(linha, 5)
                Edi_Pro.ComboBox1.Value = .Cells(linha, 7)
            ElseIf xCel = "" Then
                Edi_Pro.TextBox2.Value = ""
                Edi_Pro.TextBox3.Value = ""
                Edi_Pro.TextBox4.Value = ""
                Edi_Pro.ComboBox1.Value = ""
            End If
            linha = linha + 1
        Wend
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The main problem of your code, that you loop through all cells without displaying and therefore the textbox values will be the last found items values.

Comment: Since any string with "13" in it also contains a "1", this will indeed match such cases.  And the way that the loop is written it will return the last match in your list.  I cannot tell you how to fix this because it is not clear to me what you actually want to do.  You would need to show us what the data looks like and tell us how you can tell a "code" from everything else that is in these strings. And what to do if multiple strings have code "1".

Comment: Instr search within a string a substring. What you need i think `Range.Find` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this code and it worked. Black cat was right about the way the original code loop was set up it would give me always the last result of the loop, so I tried another approach and this worked.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
   On Error Resume Next
   Dim intervalo As Range
   Dim texto As String
   Dim codigo As Integer
   Dim pesquisa

   codigo = TextBox1.Text

   Sheets("Produtos").Select
   Set intervalo = Range("B3:G3000")

   pesquisa = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(codigo, intervalo, 2, False)
   TextBox2 = pesquisa
   pesquisa = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(codigo, intervalo, 3, False)
   TextBox3 = pesquisa
   pesquisa = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(codigo, intervalo, 4, False)
   TextBox4 = pesquisa
   pesquisa = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(codigo, intervalo, 6, False)
   ComboBox1 = pesquisa
   TextBox1.SetFocus
   TextBox1.SetFocus
    If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
       MsgBox "Não foi localizado nenhum valor correspondente ao Código", vbInformation, "Lançamento de Estoque"
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this will match first exact find. Sidenote: intervalo.Find does the same with extended capabilities. (For future use)

Comment: Nice to know. I'm still learning VBA on new job, so every new trick counts.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Match()`

No need for `On Error Resume Next` if you don't use `WorksheetFunction` - you can instead test the return value.

```vb
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
   
    Dim wsProd As Worksheet, rngMatch As Range
    Dim codigo As Long, m, tb2, tb3, tb4, cb1
    
    codigo = CLng(TextBox1.Text)
    
    Set wsProd = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Produtos")
    Set rngMatch = wsProd.Range("B3:B" & wsProd.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row)
    m = Application.Match(codigo, rngMatch, 0) 'try to find an exact match
    If Not IsError(m) Then                     'got a match?
        With rngMatch.Cells(m).EntireRow       'the whole row for the matched cell
            tb2 = .Columns("C").Value          'read the results...
            tb3 = .Columns("D").Value
            tb4 = .Columns("E").Value
            cb1 = .Columns("G").Value
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Não foi localizado nenhum valor correspondente ao Código", vbInformation, "Lançamento de Estoque"
    End If
    
    TextBox2 = tb2     'show results (or empty values)
    TextBox3 = tb3
    TextBox4 = tb4
    ComboBox1 = cb1
    
    TextBox1.SetFocus
    
End Sub
```